What the fastest way to transfer a large amount of rows from Table 1 in Database A, to Table 2 in Database B
I have a MySql database (Database A) with a table (data) and I want to move all of this data into a new table (reading) in a different MySql database (Database B).
data and reading have a different structure, and therefore I cannot just mysqldump the table into the new database. My current method (which works) is taking longer than a day. This is the query:
CREATE `uspInsertIgnoreDataInBatches`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE start_index INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE batch_size INT DEFAULT 100000;
    DECLARE total_rows INT;

    -- Get the total count of rows
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_rows
    FROM A.data
    LEFT JOIN A.device_sensor ON data.device_sensor_id = device_sensor.id
    LEFT JOIN A.sensors ON sensors.id = device_sensor.sensor_id;

    -- Loop until all rows are processed
    WHILE start_index < total_rows DO
        BEGIN
            -- Insert data in batches
            INSERT IGNORE INTO B.reading (Id, RecordedAtMT, SensorId, LocationId, SensorValue)
            SELECT data.id, data.datetime, sensors.id as sensor_id, data.location_id, data.value
            FROM A.data
            LEFT JOIN A.device_sensor ON data.device_sensor_id = device_sensor.id
            LEFT JOIN A.sensors ON sensors.id = device_sensor.sensor_id
            ORDER BY A.data.datetime DESC
            LIMIT batch_size OFFSET start_index;
        END;

        -- Move to the next batch
        SET start_index = start_index + batch_size;
    END WHILE;
END

Note: INSERT IGNORE is used because the previous table has rows which will violate the unique constraints of the new table.
I'm looking for any solution that will make this operation as quick and efficient as possible, thanks.

Can you use SELECT INTO OUTFILE and make a .csv file, then LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE it into your new table?

How many rows are you copying over and what are your column data types? Please include the explain output on the select part of the insert - select statement. How many indexes do you have on the target table?

how long does your paginated select take?

Is there an index on A.data.datetime?

If you can use SELECT INTO and LOAD DATA then the fastest is probably to pipe that through a script. eg mysql -d db1 -e "SELECT ... INTO '/dev/stdout" > mysql -d db2 -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dev/stdin' ...

Assuming you cannot use the suggested SELECT INTO OUTFILE followed by LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, you can certainly make your SP more efficient.
We have no information on the volume of data or DDL for the tables, but the timescale suggests a large dataset. A LIMIT clause with a large offset can be very slow, so instead we can track the min/max values of last datetime and id (to break ties) inserted and then use them in the WHERE clause of the next iteration.
Here's a modified (and untested) version of your SP:
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `uspInsertIgnoreDataInBatches`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE min_dt DATETIME DEFAULT '2999-12-31';
    DECLARE min_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE batch_size INT DEFAULT 10000;
    DECLARE affected_rows INT DEFAULT 1;

    -- Loop until all rows are processed
    WHILE affected_rows > 0 DO
        -- Insert data in batches
        INSERT IGNORE INTO B.reading (Id, RecordedAtMT, SensorId, LocationId, SensorValue)
        SELECT data.id, data.datetime, sensors.id, data.location_id, data.value
        FROM A.data
        LEFT JOIN A.device_sensor ON data.device_sensor_id = device_sensor.id
        LEFT JOIN A.sensors ON sensors.id = device_sensor.sensor_id
        WHERE (A.data.datetime = min_dt AND A.data.id < min_id)
        OR A.data.datetime < min_dt
        ORDER BY A.data.datetime DESC, A.data.id DESC
        LIMIT batch_size;
        
        SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO affected_rows;

        -- Move to the next batch
        SELECT Id, RecordedAtMT INTO min_id, min_dt
        FROM B.reading
        ORDER BY RecordedAtMT ASC, Id ASC
        LIMIT 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$

Indices on A.data.datetime and B.reading.RecordedAtMT are key to the performance of this approach.
If you do not need this written to the binlog, you could also disable that with set sql_log_bin = 0; assuming the definer has the SUPER priv.
